# To what extent would bad conditions slow down medieval travel?

Tags: medieval, travel

I'm writing a story set in the medieval era, and it wouldn't be a real medieval story without dealing with the nightmare of the logistics of medieval travel, nor would it be a medieval story without plenty of that said medieval travel. I know that traveling in medieval times was slow, and I've done my fair share of research about it. In every place I've looked for that research, sources always talk about speed in good conditions. But I'm writing a story where characters travel in bad conditions. How much would these conditions slow them down?

The specific example of this is that I'm writing a scene that takes place in the middle of October. Two characters are riding down to a nearby city that is about 45 miles (70 km) away. They each only have one horse, so from my research, the journey would take in good conditions about a day and a half if they stop to sleep through the night. However, this is the day after a rainstorm. While it is no longer raining, the characters are traveling on dirt road that became very muddy after the rain.

I also have some travel scenes in winter. With a large group of people, I'm not sure if my characters would stop for the winter or continue moving. They're walking on foot, and I don't know how the snow would slow them down if they kept moving.

Comment: This [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7806134/) may be helpful. It examines how different terrain types affect walking speed and metabolic expenditure.

Comment: October, October . . . *where*? Is it Italy, or is it England? Local conditions matter very much, because in medieval and early modern times travel was basically what we would call today cross country; there were no functional roads, except in the first part of the middle ages when some old Roman roads were still somewhat practicable.

Comment: I'm under the impression that any days-long travel would never be done in the winter unless there was some external urgency. Cold is man's first enemy, and you can see this in art and literature. Military casualties were more from cold and disease than enemy swords, for example. For a story, characters must obey the Gandalf rule: they arrive precisely when they mean to. I think readers are willing to believe a muddy road slowed them down. Good writing makes that a plot point, or an opportunity for character development. If it's just there, that's when it feels weird.

Comment: @fredsbend, the [Donner Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donner_Party) would probably agree with you!

Comment: @AlexP is spot on. In October, it would take me about two days to hike the 78 km from Athens to Corinth in Greece (it’s mostly flat, and even the worst weather there is not bad that time of year). In comparison, the 77 km from Bern to Lucerne in Switzerland would probably take me three days (mountainous terrain, but still mostly reasonable weather), while the 70 km from Kyiv to Fastiv in Ukraine would take at least three days, but more likely four (because in the spring and fall, the ground in the Eastern European Plain is mostly made of very deep mud).

Comment: Your question really boils down to "When conditions aren't ideal, precisely how bad are they then?" which is an obviously unanswerable question - whatever circumstance you pick is inherently answering your own question. There is no accurate calculation model for precisely which amount of weather leads to a precise change in local conditions in a specific location based on a specific horse and rider's ability to overcome the difficulties based on a specific sense of urgency to not be slowed down. Pick any specifics that you like and consider if they make reasonable sense for your story.

Comment: @AlexP not just former Roman roads.  At times, in places, some of the [rdigeways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridgeway_(road)) and [UK, Anglo-Saxon) herepaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herepath) were likely to have been pretty good.  The latter in particular were used to respond quickly to invasions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason all your research is based on good conditions is because you can always invoke enough bad conditions to bring travel to a complete stop. If you're looking for hard-and-fast numbers you're going to be disappointed. What kind of horse? Or are you walking in armor? Is it raining? Are we talkin' a light shower or a complete downpour? Is the road made of stone? Grass? Mud? Is the river you need to cross even crossable?

There are thousands of variables — far too many to give you predictable numbers about how much travel will be slowed down. *But you don't need them.*

Now that you have the best-case numbers, all that's left is to *choose based on the needs of your story* how much an individual or group must slow down — and then determine what weather conditions you need to rationalize that speed.

Comment: +1 Agree with this - some years back I had a misadventure where I walked into an area, covering about 28 km after a lunchtime start.  Two days later I was unable to walk out, even with snowshoes - in my attempt I was able to cover about 6 km in 4 hours before being unable to make any headway over a snowed-in pass and being forced to return to shelter.  Worse conditions can make travel varying degrees of slower and more tiring or outright impossible.

Comment: Quick note: I've edited out a metaphor that was causing some offense and cleaned up some comments about the situation.

Comment: @HDE226868 Cool... but I didn't read the comments as taking offense... only that they didn't understand the metaphor (unless other comments appeared later that I didn't read). The metaphor was a paraphrase of a quote from a U.S. Civil War soldier. If offense was taken, the world's skin is getting mighty thin.

Comment: Unconscious bias, removing religious things.

Comment: Looking at the revision history, I definitely would have considered "prissy little atheist [whatever]" offensive. It's hard to read that as anything but derogatory towards atheists. The context about paraphrasing a quote from a civil war soldier doesn't make it less offensive. Someone with more respectful views toward atheists would not have picked a quote like that.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the slight. I have many atheist friends. After speaking with them, they understood the metaphor. But, it is what it is. We live in a world where there is always someone who will be offended - even on someone else's behalf.

Comment: The response of specific people who personally like you and have reason to interpret your words in a positive light isn't reflective of the general population. Consider asking atheists who *don't* like you. (And what makes you assume I'm offended on someone else's behalf?)

Comment: @JBH The comments were maybe not definitive, but there were flags about the phrase, which is how the thing came to my attention.

Comment: @HDE226868 Ahh.

Comment: The edit is lame. This is always the result. We sanitize powerful religious metaphors into bland information. This is on a site that serves creative writing, btw. One who doesn't get the juxtaposition of "atheist shower" and "revival downpour" has not read enough literature.

Answer (score 2):

45 miles is easily achievable in one day on horseback. You could walk that far in two days.

When travelling, people back then would be the same as now when travelling open country. By first light they have already packed and had breakfast, so they start at sunrise, and go on until dusk. The journey is a task they want completed asap, not a sightseeing adventure.

Soldiers like the Roman legions were expected to be able to march 20 miles a day carrying gear and be able to set up a camp afterwards. It's not a huge distance to fit people.

The factors that would mean the most to your speed is what you're carrying with you. If your horse is loaded down, or is an old sickly beast, or dragging a cart, you'll need more time.

Roads are not made of mud, medieval people weren't stupid. They use the easiest paths for the weather. Snow they would use ridges, wet they would use paths over bedrock.

Comment: There are places in Europe where *everything* is made of mud in autumn and in spring. See [raspututitsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasputitsa).

Comment: @AlexP yeah, there are also swamps etc,.... medieval people used ridges or built raised roads or did pretty much anything except wade through the mud. Since the stone age even.

Comment: The point is that in large parts of Europe (e.g., the lands called today Belarus, Ukraine, most of western Russia, most of northern Poland, parts of Romania, large parts of Hungary, etc.) *there are no ridges*, and the bedrock is below hundreds of meters of mud.

Comment: @AlexP the same territory the Scythians, Sarmatians, Mongols etc travelled a hundred miles a day on sometimes?

Comment: Yes, that's the land, the [Eastern European Plain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_European_Plain). In summer and in winter once could travel on horseback easily and quite fast -- there are no significant obstacles. In the eastern and southern parts of the plain there weren't even any large forests to slow down the riders. In mud season, not so much.

Comment: @AlexP great, also they don't turn into swamps when it rains. The whole reason they don't have forests is that they don't retain enough water.  Best to avoid studies done by people who'd be out of breathe after walking to their mailbox, a puddle is impassable to them

Comment: They don't turn to swamps when it rains; the land is very [good agricultural land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernozem). They turn to deep (as is many meters deep) mud when it rains for many days, because the clay layer underlying the black soil has poor permeability, and there is very little slope to drain the water. Flat plains do that, it's normal.

Comment: @AlexP seems unlikely to me, feel free to compose your own answer around your 'many metres' of mud. 2 metres and you've buried everyone (or horse) that walks outside.

Comment: @Kilisi Would you believe studies done by modern, industrialized militaries? Back in May, the mud-inducing properties of Ukrainian soil and weather, and the effects these would have on troops, were *the* point of discussion about the war. Armies have struggled with this for centuries, it's simply not possible to move quickly or en masse over this kind of ground during the wet season.

Comment: @Cadence no I wouldn't, there's a big difference between tanks churning up the earth and thousands of men moving in column over a patch of ground for hours/days and motorised vehicles compared to a medieval group of travellers. As a forestry worker in wet weather I could be knee deep in mud if I followed behind the digger that cut the tracks, or I could walk a metre to the side on the grass and be fine.

Comment: @Kilisi Rasputitsa's effects on military activity vastly predates the arrival of tanks. Napoleon faced it in 1812, and it may have helped halt the Mongol invasion in the 13th century. Granted, even a medieval army is still quite different than a handful of travellers, but it's not like this phenomenon is unique to situations with tanks and motorised vehicles

Comment: When considering wet clay soil, an important consideration has to be whether that ground has been plowed. Here in north Texas, native prairie has grasses that hold the topsoil in place when it rains. Once it has been plowed, different grasses show up and they don't hold the topsoil as well. So, travelers trying to walk on grass don't find stable ground. Vehicles (wagons, etc.) sink deep in the mud. Photos of the first cars trying to drive farm roads show them sinking quite deep. The first people walking there do well, the next, not so well.

Comment: @DavidR as my answer mentions, medieval people are not stupid

Comment: @AlexP : this is why in winter it was easier to travel than in autumn, in regions with lots of mud in case of rainy weather: you could travel on frozen rivers, or just use sleighs.

Comment: @Kilisi : a medieval army was not just a group of travelers. They needed supplies, camping equipment, etc. which mean thousands upon thousands of horses and hundreds of carts.

Comment: @Kilisi You are correct in that they were not stupid. That meant that significant roads were built and maintained because tolls could be collected on them, or a ruler wanted the trade / pilgrimage to happen. Side roads were not maintained. Farm "roads" were just ruts in the mud. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_road_transport Thus, travel at that time really depended on where the person wanted to go.

Comment: @Kilisi It's been a while since I've seen someone on an SE network with such a high reputation so adamantly opposed to reasonable challenges to their answer, particularly when said challenges are citing such well-documented phenomena. Why do you assume that the only possibilities that can exist are immaculately-maintained roads and impassable bogs? Also, I have to agree with the other commenters in that only trade routes and major highways were paved roads. Every other "road" was a wide dirt path or even just ruts, created and "maintained" solely by frequent foot, horse, cart, or wagon travel.

Comment: @Abion47 I don't even know where the rep came from... might be an error or something

Comment: @Kilisi I've been watching the comments on your answer for a little bit, and I gotta say, yeah, this isn't really a helpful answer. I've seen some frame challenges, but saying "well, why are they walking on a dirt road when there's obviously a paved one nearby? Idiots." is not that. What can I say to a nearby paved road expect "no."

Comment: @lost_not_found I think you're reading things into my answer that don't exist, but feel free to downvote or whatever gives your day a boost. Have a good one.